# UIAlertController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am creating a `view controller` in swift with a few text fields and an `accept button` which confirms the user's input. The `accept button` also checks if any of the text fields is empty. If so, it will pop up an `alert` saying something like `it cannot be empty`. if it is not empty, it will store the input and then jump to another view.

I created an separated function called `checEmpty()` which looks like this:

```
    func checEmpty(title: String, object: UITextField) -> (Bool) {
        if object.text.isEmpty {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid input", 
                message:"\(title) cannot be empty", 
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", 
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

And I call this function in the `acceptButton` action:

```
   @IBAction func acceptButton(sender: UIButton){
         if(checEmpty("Event", object: eventName) && checEmpty("Priority", object: Priority)
         { 
                //if not empty, confirm the user input
               // ...
         }
```

When I run it, the alert message works fine but for some reason the console shows this:

> 2015-08-03 12:11:50.656 FinishItToday[13777:688070] >'s window is not equal to
>   's view's window!

Can anyone tell me why this warning appears? Thank you very much!

PS. 
What I want it to do is that if any of the text field is empty, show the alert and then stay at the same page. If none of them are empty, then perform the segue and switch to another view. The code above works fine except the warning.

Comment: Well I still don't know the meaning of that warning but I somehow fixed the problem by overriding the shouldPerformSegue function, letting the segue stop working when there are empty text field. Now I believe there may be some conflicts between performViewController() and segue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Priority: UITextField!

    @IBAction func acceptButton(sender: UIButton){

        if checEmpty("Event", object: eventName) && checEmpty("Priority", object: Priority){
            println("Both Text Fields Are Empty")
        }
    }

    func checEmpty(title: String, object: UITextField) -> (Bool) {
        if object.text.isEmpty {

            var Alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid input", message: "\(title) cannot be empty", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel, handler: { action in
                println("Click of cancel button")
            }))
            self.presentViewController(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider adding some commentary to your answer that explains what the problem was and how your code addresses this problem

Comment: I'm sorry but the warning still exists. Could you please tell me where the problem was?

Comment: Check out this sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=81855653171481635163

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It somehow inspired me since the only difference between your code and mine is that my code also has segue. So I thought maybe there are some conflicts between  self.presentViewController() and segue. Now I fixed the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to for alert view controller in swift. It may help you.

```
 import UIKit

 protocol alertViewDelegate {
     func actionActive(index:Int, tag:Int)
 }

 class AlertView: NSObject {

 var delegate:alertViewDelegate!

 func showAlert(title:String, message:String, actionName:NSArray, tag:Int) ->    UIAlertController {
         var alertController:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

         for str: AnyObject in actionName {
         let alertAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: str as! String, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                 self.delegate.actionActive(actionName.indexOfObject(str), tag:tag)
             })
             alertController.addAction(alertAction)
         }
         return alertController;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Could you tell me why there is such a warning out there please?

Comment: go through this. You will get the answer.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677447/error-uiviews-window-is-not-equal-to-another-views-window

Comment: You are using self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) for present new controller and also using return false to your view controller. is it right? please change your method it will resolve.

Comment: Thanks.  I did forget that the button also has a segue being attached to it. The link is useful.