# Error A's window is not equal to B's view's windows

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, model-view-controller, segue

So I have a problem during performing a segue between 2 view controllers.

Let's call the 2 view controllers

A: LoginViewController

B: ViewController

[image]

In B I have a "Log Out" button (It is a left bar button item), when it triggers a function when it's clicked, like such, and call up dismissViewController and goes back to A.

```
@IBAction func logOutButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let actionController = UIAlertController(title: "Log out", message: "Are you sure you want to log out?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){UIAlertAction in
        self.prefs.setInteger(0, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
        self.prefs.setInteger(0, forKey: "PERMISSIONTOLOADDATA")
        self.prefs.synchronize()

        print("User logged out")
        socket.disconnect()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){UIAlertAction in
        print("Test: Log out action cancelled")
    }

    actionController.addAction(okAction)
    actionController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Nothing is wrong here, yet, but when I enter my ID in A's text field and click **Login** button, it triggers error like this:

```
2016-02-02 17:33:12.879 iCare[3852:190330] <UIView: 0x7facd153cfd0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); alpha = 0.95; autoresize = W+H; tintColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7facd153d140>>'s window is not equal to <UINavigationController: 0x7facd187ae00>'s view's window!
```

Login Button's code:

```
@IBAction func LoginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let logInUserID = loginPatientID.text
    let logInUserIDUpper = logInUserID?.uppercaseString
    if (logInUserIDUpper!.isEmpty){
        displayAlertMessage("Please enter your Patient ID!")
        return
    }else{
        print("Test: requesting login permission from database")
        loginSocket.emit("loginRequest", logInUserIDUpper!)
        print("Test: requested")

        loginSocket.on("loginReply") {data, ack in
            let jsonLogin = JSON(data)
            if jsonLogin[0].intValue == 1{
                print("Test: ID Matched, putting up ViewController")

                self.prefs.setObject(logInUserIDUpper, forKey: "AppUserID")
                self.prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                self.prefs.synchronize()
                loginSocket.disconnect()

                self.loginPatientID.resignFirstResponder()
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoVC", sender: self)
            }else if jsonLogin[0].intValue == 0{
                self.displayAlertMessage("Sorry, you are not assigned to this program")
            }else if jsonLogin[0].intValue == 3{
                self.displayAlertMessage("Internet is not stable, please try again later")
                print("Test: Query problem")
            }else{
                print("Test: not getting anything from ID database")
            }
        }//socket.on
    }//else
}//login button
```

I referred to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677447/error-uiviews-window-is-not-equal-to-another-views-window)

and figured that my problem is different from Mr. Paka because my log out button didn't perform a segue but rather dismiss a the view controller itself, which could in turn causes overlapping.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: @J.Doe: Did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Create the segue from VC's view to target VC (instead of from a button to target VC). This will solve that "window is not equal" issue