# How do I read this statement from my Xcode Debugger?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

When I transition between view controllers, the two latest ones I have created, in the debug, I am getting a large string that I'm not quite able to get to the bottom of.
Can anyone point me in the right direction/ help me to understand this and find the problem I've made?

I have compared all of my documents/view controllers to my working/non-error ones and can't find anything obvious.

```
2019-02-12 18:47:20.879463+1300 Techsupport[15324:9474292] <UIView:0x7ff96154a2f0; frame = (0 0; 375 812); autoresize = W+H; tintColor =UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.149131 0 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray:0x600002c474e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000021d42c0>>'s window is not equal` to <Techsupport.EslViewController: 0x7ff9618fd800>'s view's window!
```

Comment: Can you upload the UI?

Comment: @SachinVas https://ibb.co/qshmC8R is the basic UI

Comment: Not the Storyboard, it adds to the confusion. Can you show the end result, i.e device UI.

Comment: Like this? I’m still slightly confused by your wording... https://ibb.co/XkYh3DF

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Can you upload the photo of the view controller in which you are seeing the above-mentioned behavior?

Comment: ok, here is a link, so pretty much, all of my other transitions are OK, its only the last one i click on, on this video that is the issue! please take a look! https://vimeo.com/316713882

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677447/error-uiviews-window-is-not-equal-to-another-views-window, possible duplicate?

Comment: Duplicate view controller or duplicate segue function?

Comment: Not ViewController, it looks like you have a segue which is set to trigger automatically and also programmatically in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188253/discussion-between-taylor-styles-and-sachin-vas).

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to read if you take out all the details about the view:

> `Techsupport[15324:9474292] <UIView>'s window is not equal to <Techsupport.EslViewController: 0x7ff9618fd800>'s view's window!`

It's hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing some of your code, but fundamentally the view that the error is complaining about (located at 0x7ff96154a2f0) belongs to a view hierarchy in a window that's different from the one that the view controller's view is in.

Here are some things to consider:

- How are each of these views created?
- Do you *expect* to have two windows? (Most iOS apps only have one.)
- What are you trying to do with the view in question?

A good way to start is to set a breakpoint at the spot where the error occurs, and then work backward until you figure out where the view in question comes from.

Comment: Ok, so each of my 'Views' at the moment is pretty much their own view controller. I did do a bit of googling and found that apparently there isnt too much of an issue in having multiple view controllers if that's what you were referring too. The view in question is when I Segue between "AppkitViewController" and "Esl View Controller". what I find odd. is that "ESLViewController" is one of my MAIN menus and any other segue TO here, doesn't give me this in the debug? here is a video of me replicating it if that would be useful: https://vimeo.com/316713882

Comment: Its fine to have multiple view controllers -- most apps do -- but normally there's just one window. A window is a particular kind of view that's the root of a view hierarchy, i.e a window is the only view that has no superview. It could be that the "second" window doesn't actually exist, and the error is just telling you that the view in the error isn't inside the window that the view controller's view is in. Take a look at the `window` property for both views and see if they both seem valid.

Comment: Ahh ok, I see what you mean! @SachinVas above was correct, it was me doing an automatic button to segue as well as calling the function programmatically at the same time. 
The way my app is (semi) designed is to mainly have two "windows" for my employers two types of PCB. from the different types, I have troubleshooting/ quick starts for each. meaning that its got kind of a tree starting from a login, choose the type of PCB, then out to the troubleshooting based on the panel, ive just found this easier to design with multiple view controllers. thank you for heaps for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

As @Sachin Vas said, "it looks like you have a segue which is set to trigger automatically and also programmatically in the code." he was correct, I did have a mistake where I had called the function programmatically as well as automatically. Thanks for everyone's help!